# fluent nhibernate string to enum select query example

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I am using fluent nhibernate. I have a database column storing strings `VALUE1`, `VALUE2`. They need to be converted to enum values while fetching.
Basically, I can't figure out :-

1) what needs to happen to this enum so that nhibernate understands and can convert string rows to their respective enum values.
(if enumString ? then how to use ? / other suggestions)

2) `query for the entity where EnumField = value1`

Here's the code to create the context for the problem.

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}

class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.EnumField);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = Fluently.Configure().Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>())
                                .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true))
                                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=nhtest;Integrated Security=True"))
                                .BuildSessionFactory();
        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
             **need a way to query for all `Value1`** 
        }

    }
}
```

So far stuff I've seen only deals with a generic save command, I haven't found any query examples

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Fluent NHibernate, the work is already done for you.  Persisting enums as strings is Fluent NHibernate's default behavior.

**NHibernate** (without Fluent NH) by default persists enums as ints.  **Fluent NH** changes this behavior by applying the `GenericEnumMapper<TEnum>` type to the property mapping (see the [code](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/PropertyPart.cs)).

Since the matter of specifying the mapping has been already handled by Fluent NH, the remainder of your code can safely be ignorant of the fact that it is stored as a string in the database.  For example:

```
var result = session.Query<Entity>()
    .Where(x => x.EnumField == SomeEnum.Value1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok it seems to works with a manual mapping, but only incase of an exact match ( `Value1` or `myValue1` wont map to `VALUE1` or `MYVALUE1` in db).  

with an automapped entity it doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: What database engine are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?  Does it treat strings as case-sensitive by default?  Or is there a case-sensitive collation applied to the column?

Comment: SQL server 2008, these strings are all existing data that i must work with. There's nothing in this table that would auto modify them (no schema/triggers ..)

Comment: Understood - but if it seems like NHibernate is filtering the enum in a case-sensitive manner, then that is a SQL Server issue, not an NHibernate issue.  You'll probably have the same result executing `SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE EnumField = 'Value1'` directly in SQL Management Studio.  SQL Server's default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  That "CI" near the end means "case-insensitive", which is what you want here.  Collations can be applied to a whole database, or to individual columns.  A collation like SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: seems to work. Selecting `SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE EnumField = 'Value1' ` can pull up `VALUE1` as well